# Using module.exports to expose React class instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I know the title is maybe a bit confusing. Here's a code sample:

```
//First.js
export default class First extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    module.exports.push = route => {
       this.refs.router.push(route)
    }

    module.exports.pop = () => {
       this.refs.router.pop()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Router ref="router"/>
  }
}
```

and then

```
//second.js
import { push, pop } from "first.js"

//class instantiation and other code
push("myRoute")
```

Code pen: https://codepen.io/Stefvw93/pen/bLyyNG?editors=0010

The intent is to avoid using the withRouter function from react-router. So instead, expose push/pop history functions from a single instance of react-router's browserRouter component. It works by creating a reference to the router instance (ref="router") and then exporting this instance by doing something like module.exports.push=this.refs.router.push

Comment: Is this a question?  I can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can not declare any dynamic exports, the only way would to export `push` and `pop` would be to export some sort of mutable container object first, and then modify it afterwards. e.g Export immediately an empty object, and set its `push` and `pop` properties in the constructor.

```
//First.js
export const router = {};

export default class First extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    router.push = route => {
       this.refs.router.push(route)
    };

    router.pop = () => {
       this.refs.router.pop()
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <Router ref="router"/>
  }
}
```

and then

```
//second.js
import { router } from "first.js"

//class instantiation and other code
router.push("myRoute")
```

But there are big downsides of doing it this way:

- you’ll end up using last rendered router instance
- there’s no checking if such instance already exists
- you can not have multiple routers using the same pattern

I’d prefer being explicit and writing `withRouter` wherever I need router, because:

- it is not subject to race conditions — you either have a router or you don’t, in which case you get a nice error log
- it communicates your intention clearly, and documentation about `withRouter` exists
- uses well—known and elegant HoC pattern
- allows you to have multiple routers

Long story short, mutable global state is bad, just don’t do it.